# How can I download data from a data base from postgres in a shiny app?

Tags: r, postgresql, csv, download, shiny

I have a `shiny` app and I would like to download in a csv file data selected by the user, through a query from `postgres`. These data are stored in a `postgresql` data base. How can I do it?

Comment: Jose - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - this will probably explain why you've gotten two downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host='Youhost', port='PORT', dbname='YourDBName',
             user='USER', password='PASSWORD')
dbListTables(con)

data <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM SomeTable")


dbDisconnect(con)

dbUnloadDriver(drv)
```

Connect to your database. Pull data using SQL and store it with your preferred format.